# How about a StackExchange site for crafts?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I'm a fan of crafts and crafting. Basically everything that [Michael's](http://www.michaels.com/) sells. So today I was reading about heat embossing and I thought, "jeez, I really want to ask someone whether the ink or the embossing powder controls the color more." Then I thought, "what a perfect question for the Craft StackExchange." Except, *gasp* **THERE ISN'T ONE!**

I therefore propose that a new StackExchange site be created. A site for all things craft. I'm talking knitting, paper cut-outs, making hand soap, scrap-booking, stamping, glue guns, beads, crochet hooks, crayons, pens, markers, pencils, charcoal, vellum, jewelry, modelling clay, paints, basically all things nifty or crafty.

And heat embossing.

Because I still want my question answered.

Comment: I'll support this. Good idea

Answer (score 11):

You can make a proposal for such a site (if one doesn't exist already) on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the staging area for new StackExchange sites.

In this case, it looks like the [Crafts, Crafting and Crafters](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24184/crafts-crafting-and-crafters) proposal might
be what you're looking for. It's currently in the commitment stage, so if enough people
commit to participating on the site, it will launch as a new beta site.